# How to set the value of radio button alert in Ionic 2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, alert, ionic3

I have radio button alert that contain more than 12 options and I want to check the option that is equal than my variable value.

I was use if statement to did this thing with a less than 4 options. But now I have more than 12 option so I wish there is easier way to check the value of my variable and select the equal option.

---edit---

This is a part of my html

```
<button ion-button clear full (click)="selectColor(x.color)">{{x.color}}</button>
```

.ts Function ( **I want a better way to select the radiobutton of alert (if any)** )

```
selectColor(color){
    let alert1 = this.alertCtrl.create();
alert1.setTitle('Color Theme');
    if(color=="red"){
        alert1.addInput({
            type: 'radio',
            label: 'Red',
            value: 'red',
            checked: true
        });
    }else{
        alert1.addInput({
            type: 'radio',
            label: 'Red',
            value: 'red',
        });
    }
    if(color=="pink"){
        alert1.addInput({
            type: 'radio',
            label: 'Pink',
            value: 'pink',
            checked: true
        });
    }else{
        alert1.addInput({
            type: 'radio',
            label: 'Pink',
            value: 'pink'
        });
    }
    if(color=="purple"){
        alert1.addInput({
            type: 'radio',
            label: 'Purple',
            value: 'purple',
            checked: true
        });
    }else{
        alert1.addInput({
            type: 'radio',
            label: 'Purple',
            value: 'purple'
        });
    }
    if(color=="blue"){
        alert1.addInput({
            type: 'radio',
            label: 'Blue',
            value: 'blue',
            checked: true
        });
    }else{
        alert1.addInput({
            type: 'radio',
            label: 'Blue',
            value: 'blue'
        });
    }
    ...
alert1.addButton('Cancel');
alert1.addButton({
  text: 'Okay',
  handler: data => {
            ...
  }
});
alert1.present();
}
```

Comment: Could you please add the code to the post?

Comment: @sebaferreras yes I did.. I put my long way to check radiobutton of alert but wish there is a short way to help me in case I have more than 10 or 12 radiobuttons

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there's an easy way to do that. You can just add the condition in the `checked` property like this:

```
selectColor(color){
    let alert1 = this.alertCtrl.create();
    alert1.setTitle('Color Theme');

    alert1.addInput({
        type: 'radio',
        label: 'Red',
        value: 'red',
        checked: color === "red"
    });

    alert1.addInput({
        type: 'radio',
        label: 'Pink',
        value: 'pink',
        checked: color === "pink"
    });

    alert1.addInput({
        type: 'radio',
        label: 'Purple',
        value: 'purple',
        checked: color === "purple"
    });

    alert1.addInput({
        type: 'radio',
        label: 'Blue',
        value: 'blue',
        checked: color === "blue"
    });

    // ...

    alert1.addButton('Cancel');
    alert1.addButton({
        text: 'Okay',
        handler: data => {
            // ...
        }
    });

    alert1.present();
}
```

**EDIT**

There's also a better way to add all the colors, by using a `forEach` loop and an array with all the colors:

```
selectColor(color){
    let alert1 = this.alertCtrl.create();
    alert1.setTitle('Color Theme');

    // Add the new colors here!
    const colors = ['Red', 'Pink', 'Purple', 'Blue'];

    colors.forEach(color => {
        alert1.addInput({
            type: 'radio',
            label: color,
            value: color.toLowerCase(),
            checked: color === color.toLowerCase()
        });
    });

    // ...

    alert1.addButton('Cancel');
    alert1.addButton({
        text: 'Okay',
        handler: data => {
            // ...
        }
    });

    alert1.present();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was need to repeat first code 5 to 7 times but you save my heart with your second code. thank u again

Comment: Glad to hear that :)

Comment: how can i set datetime input field in alert?